# How to set linebreakMode of navigation title in TruncatingMiddle

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I use titleTextAttributes to set lineBreakmode in TruncatingMiddle.
But I fail to show me the title with linebreakmode.
What's wrong with me?
Thanks.

```
let paragraph = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraph.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingMiddle

self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [
        NSFontAttributeName: defaultTitleFont ?? "" ,
        NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraph ]
```

Answer (score 3):

From your question, what i get is you want a multiline title in your navigation bar, to accomplish so, you can simply do the following:

```
 let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:400, height:50))
          label.backgroundColor = .clear
          label.numberOfLines = 2
          label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16.0)
          label.textAlignment = .center
          label.textColor = .black
          label.text = "This is a\nmultiline string for the navBar"
          self.navigationItem.titleView = label
```

I hope it will solve your issue.

Comment: why you are not applied this `label.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingMiddle` instead of `a\nmultiline`

Comment: Because this mode is used for single-line layout; using it with multiline text truncates the text into a single line.

Comment: then what about `numberOfLines = 0`

Comment: `numberOfLines = 0` , makes a label multiline.
if you set the `numberOfLines = 1` , and have some big text to set in your label. By using .byTruncatingMiddle will give you output like this : This is a multiline......for the navBar

Comment: i asked the ?'er to accept the answer, if it worked for him :) you can also vote up my answer, if it helped you :) :)